Validate that Nuget packages are the latest version available?
Is there any way to automatically validate Nuget package configuration, to check that the latest versions available are being used in a project - e.g. by throwing a build error.
This would apply to both building in visual studio, and command-line MSBuild.

Hi Peregrine, I have updated my answer, you can take a look, it should be able to meet your requirements. :)

Update:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CheckForOutdatedPackages" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="dotnet list $(ProjectPath) package --outdated" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutdatedPackagesOutput" />
        </Exec>
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Checking for outdated packages..." />
        <Error Condition=" $(OutdatedPackagesOutput.Contains('has the following updates to its packages')) " Text="Outdated packages detected. Please update the packages." />
    </Target>

</Project>

The above is a demo, and there is a package named 'Moq' which is not latest, you will get this if not update the packages:

Original Answer:
Take a look at this:
NuKeeper
After installing it, you can using the below task to update the packages via the command:
Exec Task
